# What optimization method to choose for 2 variables with restrictions?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, algorithms

I need to calculate the optimal amount of ATM load. I have 2 integer variables that need to be optimized: the load amount and the collection frequency. There are also a number of limitations. the cost function will be the costs associated with the storage of money and the costs of collection and I will need to minimize it.
Which optimization method would best suit this task?
thank.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I thought to use the simplex method, but it is extremely inconvenient to translate my task into linear programming, so I wanted to see alternatives among non-linear methods.

Comment: The method depends on the problem. Your problem statement is too vague. With 2 variables though, just graph it.

Comment: as I said, the variables are the amount of loading and the frequency of collection. both variables are related. ATMs are in different locations. I need to find such a load amount that would satisfy the demand, as well as reduce the amount of unused funds, in other words, the optimal load amount. the second variable will tell you how often you need to replenish an ATM.

Comment: Still no problem statement. Vague chat is not a problem statement.

Comment: The second variable (collection rate) is equal to a number in the range of 1-30. The cost function is collection costs = collection costs + money insurance + interest rate. I need to minimize this function, that is, find the ratio of the amount of ATM loading and collection frequency (how many times you need to replenish the balance of the ATM) at which costs will be minimal